# How to make this plot with python

Tags: python, dataset, matplotlib

I want to draw plot by python based on this data

```
Id     Duration (s)       BinaryLabel
1          5                 correct
2          4                incorrect  
3          2                incorrect  
4          3                incorrect  
5          9                 correct
6          6                 correct
7          12               incorrect
```

My data is with 800 rows. and the duration is going from 0 to 55 seconds

My X axis contain duration column and I want it to be divided like: 0-----5-----10------15------20-----...-----55

and the Y should contain the percent of 'correct' values.

I.e. :

from 0 to 5, I will have 25% correct,

from 5 to 10 I will have 100% correct .etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can modify my code:

```
   import numpy as np

   Duration_ = np.random.choice(range(0,56), 10000)


   Binary_Level = []

   b_ =["correct", "incorrect"]

   Binary_Level = np.random.choice(b_, 10000)

   import pandas as pd

   dd = pd.DataFrame({'Duration_': Duration_, 'Binary_Level': 
      Binary_Level})

   xr_ = list(range(0,56,5))

   y_ = []

   for i in range(0,(len(xr_)-1)):

       a_ = np.logical_and(dd['Duration_'].values>=xr_[i], 
       dd['Duration_'].values<xr_[i+1])
       b_ = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(dd['Duration_'].values>=xr_[i], 
       dd['Duration_'].values<xr_[i+1]),
                               dd['Binary_Level'].values=='correct')
       y_.append(sum(b_)/sum(a_))

    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xr_[1:12], y_)
```

[image]

Comment: thank bonez001 it works perfectly